# Not able to get Null claims when I use where condition on a column

Tags: pyspark

Here's my code:

```
valuesA = [('Pirate',1),('Monkey',2),('Ninja',3),('Spaghetti',None)]
TableA = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['name','id'])

TableA.show()
+---------+----+
|     name|  id|
+---------+----+
|   Pirate|   1|
|   Monkey|   2|
|    Ninja|   3|
|Spaghetti|null|
+---------+----+

TableA.where(TableA.id != 2).show()
+------+---+
|  name| id|
+------+---+
|Pirate|  1|
| Ninja|  3|
+------+---+
```

Why I am not able to get Null value row in the output?

I also get the following warnings:

```
19/11/20 16:54:22 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
19/11/20 16:54:22 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
19/11/20 16:54:23 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL is *ANSI SQL* compliant, which means that by default `null` values will only ever be picked up by your query if mentioned explicitly. 
You need to change your query to:

```
TableA.where("id <> 2 or id is null").show()
+---------+----+
|     name|  id|
+---------+----+
|   Pirate|   1|
|    Ninja|   3|
|Spaghetti|null|
+---------+----+
```